# How to do a release using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, release

I am looking for a solution to do a jenkins release(not for java application) with gradle.
I want to add details about the release(nexus artifact details..etc) in a properties file and the release a version

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Jenkinsfile?
Just call your gradle file like this (for scripted pipeline)

```
    ...
    stage('Build') {    
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            sh "./gradlew build"
        }
    }
    ...
```

Here it is up to which gradle tasks creates your build. Maybe you have a gradle task with named buildRelease or whatever it needs for you. All the rest about version numbering and nexus you should do via gradle. For Nexus e.g. use maven-publish.

Comment: i have take artifact from nexus and unzip to deploy the same in a remote deployment location

Comment: i am using declarative pipeline

Comment: you could execute the following in jenkins to execute this shell script remotely on your deployment machine: sh "ssh -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i ./certificate.pem yourjenkinsMaster.com 'nc %h %p'\" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i ./certificate.pem yourUser@100.100.100.yourDeploymentMachine wget... nexus and all other scripts"